# Salesforce Service Cloud Automation Action

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm currently working on the Service Cloud Specialist Superbadge on Trailhead.  And frankly, I'm stuck entirely on Challenge 7, "Build case and agent automation" where I get the comment, "Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
We can't find an automated action in the Cloudy Weather template. Ensure you create the Cloudy Weather Resolution automated action."

I've worked on this for over a week now and cannot figure it out.  Willing to hire a tutor or instructor if one is available.  My issue is, I think, is that I cannot seem to figure out how to add the Quick Action automated action into the Cloudy Weather template.

I cannot find an email component to add to the page layout nor anything else I can add, from what I've seen on screenshots.

I would certainly appreciate some kind of instruction, screenshot, tutoring, or even a reference to a tutor.  Keep in mind, I've search all over, so any links to Google or trailheads, I've likely scoured through them already.

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of working on this, I finally found a large and very important clue to this.  Apparently the Playgrounds have serious issues of not working right, and often there are missing components.

I wracked my brains on this for a long long time, but found that after I created a New Playground and stepped back and re-did the instructions, the components which were clearly not added to the prior Playground were now there.

This is the 2nd time I've noticed this problem with this particular challenge.  If it doesn't work, there is something wrong, and the only real way to work around is to create a new playground and step back a little.

Fortunately, each challenge, while they are built one upon the other, often can be done separately in sections without having to go too far.  It is frustrating, and even unprofessional that these bugs exist, but this does appear to be the only solution.